# How can I get the animation content to appear in safari?

Tags: css, css-animations

I have an animation where the text content changes every few seconds, it seems to work perfectly in firefox and chrome, but in Safari the animation runs, but the content doesn't show. I can't find any known compatibility issues with Safari?

example:
https://codepen.io/gazrobbo/pen/dEMVRE

```
<body>
  <div class="sp-container">
    <div class="sp-content">
      <h2 class="frame-1"></h2>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

body {
  background: blue;
}

.sp-container {
  grid-area: text;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
  justify-content: center;
  justify-items: center;
}

.sp-content {
  -webkit-transform: translatey(-50%);
  transform: translatey(-50%);
  width: 70%;
  height: 40%;
  z-index: 1000;
  text-align: center;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.sp-container h2 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 25vh;
  line-height: 4rem;
  height: 90px;
  margin-top: -50px;
  font-size: 3.5rem;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  color: transparent;
  font-family: beyond_infinity_-_demoregular;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 600px) {
  .sp-container h2 {
    top: 30vh;
    font-size: 4.75rem;
  }
}

.sp-container h2.frame-1 {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 1s;
  animation-delay: 1s;
  /* animation: blurFadeInOut1 15s ease-in backwards; */
  -webkit-animation-name: blurFadeInOut1;
  animation-name: blurFadeInOut1;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 15s;
  animation-duration: 15s;
  -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in;
  animation-timing-function: ease-in;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: backwards;
  animation-fill-mode: backwards;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

.frame-1:after {
  content: "";
  -webkit-animation-delay: 1s;
  animation-delay: 1s;
  /* animation: blurFadeInOuttext 15s ease-in backwards; */
  -webkit-animation-name: blurFadeInOuttext;
  animation-name: blurFadeInOuttext;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 15s;
  animation-duration: 15s;
  -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in;
  animation-timing-function: ease-in;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: backwards;
  animation-fill-mode: backwards;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

@-webkit-keyframes blurFadeInOut1 {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    text-shadow: 0px 0px 40px #fff;
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.3);
    transform: scale(1.3);
  }

  5%,
  15% {
    opacity: 1;
    text-shadow: 0px 0px 1px #fff;
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
    transform: scale(1);
  }

  20% {
    opacity: 0;
    text-shadow: 0px 0px 50px #fff;
    -webkit-transform: scale(0);
    transform: scale(0);
  }

  21% {
    opacity: 0;
    text-shadow: 0px 0px 40px #fff;
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.3);
    transform: scale(1.3);
    content: "2";
  }

  25%,
  35% {
    opacity: 1;
    text-shadow: 0px 0px 1px #fff;
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
    transform: scale(1);
  }

  40% {
    opacity: 0;
    text-shadow: 0px 0px 50px #fff;
    -webkit-transform: scale(0);
    transform: scale(0);
  }

  41% {
    opacity: 0;
    text-shadow: 0px 0px 40px #fff;
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.3);
    transform: scale(1.3);
    content: "3";
  }

  45%,
  55% {
    opacity: 1;
    text-shadow: 0px 0px 1px #fff;
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
    transform: scale(1);
  }

  60% {
    opacity: 0;
    text-shadow: 0px 0px 50px #fff;
    -webkit-transform: scale(0);
    transform: scale(0);
  }

  61% {
    opacity: 0;
    text-shadow: 0px 0px 40px #fff;
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.3);
    transform: scale(1.3);
  }

  65%,
  75% {
    opacity: 1;
    text-shadow: 0px 0px 1px #fff;
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
    transform: scale(1);
  }

  80% {
    opacity: 0;
    text-shadow: 0px 0px 50px #fff;
    -webkit-transform: scale(0);
    transform: scale(0);
  }

  81% {
    opacity: 0;
    text-shadow: 0px 0px 40px #fff;
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.3);
    transform: scale(1.3);
  }

  85%,
  95% {
    opacity: 1;
    text-shadow: 0px 0px 1px #fff;
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
    transform: scale(1);
  }

  100% {
    opacity: 0;
    text-shadow: 0px 0px 50px #fff;
    -webkit-transform: scale(0);
    transform: scale(0);
  }
}

@keyframes blurFadeInOut1 {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    text-shadow: 0px 0px 40px #fff;
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.3);
    transform: scale(1.3);
  }

  5%,
  15% {
    opacity: 1;
    text-shadow: 0px 0px 1px #fff;
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
    transform: scale(1);
  }

  20% {
    opacity: 0;
    text-shadow: 0px 0px 50px #fff;
    -webkit-transform: scale(0);
    transform: scale(0);
  }

  21% {
    opacity: 0;
    text-shadow: 0px 0px 40px #fff;
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.3);
    transform: scale(1.3);
    content: "2";
  }

  25%,
  35% {
    opacity: 1;
    text-shadow: 0px 0px 1px #fff;
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
    transform: scale(1);
  }

  40% {
    opacity: 0;
    text-shadow: 0px 0px 50px #fff;
    -webkit-transform: scale(0);
    transform: scale(0);
  }

  41% {
    opacity: 0;
    text-shadow: 0px 0px 40px #fff;
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.3);
    transform: scale(1.3);
    content: "3";
  }

  45%,
  55% {
    opacity: 1;
    text-shadow: 0px 0px 1px #fff;
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
    transform: scale(1);
  }

  60% {
    opacity: 0;
    text-shadow: 0px 0px 50px #fff;
    -webkit-transform: scale(0);
    transform: scale(0);
  }

  61% {
    opacity: 0;
    text-shadow: 0px 0px 40px #fff;
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.3);
    transform: scale(1.3);
  }

  65%,
  75% {
    opacity: 1;
    text-shadow: 0px 0px 1px #fff;
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
    transform: scale(1);
  }

  80% {
    opacity: 0;
    text-shadow: 0px 0px 50px #fff;
    -webkit-transform: scale(0);
    transform: scale(0);
  }

  81% {
    opacity: 0;
    text-shadow: 0px 0px 40px #fff;
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.3);
    transform: scale(1.3);
  }

  85%,
  95% {
    opacity: 1;
    text-shadow: 0px 0px 1px #fff;
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
    transform: scale(1);
  }

  100% {
    opacity: 0;
    text-shadow: 0px 0px 50px #fff;
    -webkit-transform: scale(0);
    transform: scale(0);
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes blurFadeInOuttext {
  6% {
    content: "Creative Concepts";
  }

  26% {
    content: "Brand Management";
  }

  46% {
    content: "Reprographics";
  }

  66% {
    content: "Flexo HD";
  }

  86% {
    content: "Website Development";
  }

  100% {
    content: "Website Development";
  }
}

@keyframes blurFadeInOuttext {
  6% {
    content: "Creative Concepts";
  }

  26% {
    content: "Brand Management";
  }

  46% {
    content: "Reprographics";
  }

  66% {
    content: "Flexo HD";
  }

  86% {
    content: "Website Development";
  }

  100% {
    content: "Website Development";
  }
}
```

I have tried changing to 5 individual animations, this works, but I would rather keep it as 1 animation if I could get it working.

Ideally, I want the text to change content and display after each fade in and out action.

Answer (score -1):

Use Animate.css library , Example

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <title>TODO supply a title</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet"        href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/3.7.0/animate.min.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1 class="animated jello">Ahmed Mansour</h1>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: As I mentioned in the [your previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/23058705), the OP's problem is that he already has animation code but his animation code is working in Firefox and Chrome, but not in Safari. He is asking **why**. He is not asking for an animation library. Though, if Animate.css can replicate his exact animation needs, you need to explain more aside from showing him how to `link` to it.